# `ResamplingMethod -> None` in `TimeSeries` does NOT take any effect in v10.1

Tags: bugs, time-series

**Possible bug in v10.1**

---

`ResamplingMethod -> None` in `TimeSeries` does NOT take any effect in v10.1.
Try:

```
ts = TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[{{123, 3}, {130, 3}, {124, 3}, {122, 9}}, 
ResamplingMethod -> None], ResamplingMethod -> None];
ts/@{125.5,122.5}
(*{0. +Missing[], 6.}*)
```

The answer is supposed to be `{Missing[], Missing[]}`.

Can anyone help me work this out?

---

**Update:**
Thanks @2012rcampion for the comment:
Changing the `ResamplingMethod` to `{"Constant",Missing[]}` is a temporary workaround in v10.1.

Comment: ts[125.5] // Rationalize

Comment: @BobHanlon , the thing is that not only Missing[] is not correctly return but also the positions which should be Missing[] are actually set with interpolated values. for e.g.: `ts[122.5]`.

Comment: This may be a bug.  I get `{Missing[], Missing[]}` on 10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: What happens if you try `ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", Missing[]}`?

Comment: Thanks @2012rcampion, the `Constant` method works. I'm deeply disappointed by the recent updates by WRI, where the unmentioned features are in fact bugs. The funny thing is that the bugs seem to be rotating but never disappear.

Comment: @sunt05 Which bugs are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, but an intended design change. The motivation is that `TimeSeries` is meant for those time-series that support resampling.

Zero order interpolation is supported, example:

`TimeSeries[Range[3], Automatic, 
    ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]`

If your time series is not meant to support resampling then `EventSeries` would most likely be a better choice than `TimeSeries`.

Comment: OK, I know `EventSeries` can used for such scenarios. However, what is meaning of `ResamplingMethod -> None` for `TimeSeries` then? At least, according to the documentation, this is a valid option for `TimeSeries` and did what it is supposed to do in the previous versions. So I cannot accept the saying that it is "an intended design".

Comment: `TimeSeries[..., ResamplingMethod->None]` will now default to linear interpolation, as can be verified by checking the `InputForm` of the resulting `TimeSeries` object. The documentation should be clarified on this issue.

Comment: This is really bad. There is no reason for changing the default behavior of a function without clear notification. And I'd rather consider this change (i.e. `TimeSeries[..., ResamplingMethod->None]` to linear interpolation) as a redundant design since the default setting of `ResamplingMethod` has already been linear interpolation.